# Why am I getting an argument exception when attempting to delete a file?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm running the following code to delete a file that does exist:

```
 try
 {
      var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
      var path = rendition.OfflineLocation.Replace(folder.Path, "");
      var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);
      await file.DeleteAsync();
 }
 catch (FileNotFoundException)
 {

 }
```

When this runs the `file.DeleteAsync();` gives an `ArgumentException`, with the message `Value does not fall within the expected range.`

I can't find any information anywhere why I would be getting this.  Any ideas?

Call Stack:

> at Windows.Storage.StorageFile.DeleteAsync()
>     at Lightning.Services.DownloaderService.d__36.MoveNext() in e:\\Services\DownloaderService.cs:line 120

Line 120 is the DeleteAsync line.

Comment: You can first start by debugging, catching the exception, calling `ToString()` on it to capture its true detail, then [edit] your question to add this very important, yet oddly lacking, information.

Comment: Um, I did debug, that's how I know what line is causing the exception, what exception is being thrown, and the message of the exception is.  There is no inner exception.

Comment: Added stack to the question, that's all the stack trace it's giving me.

Comment: That's a mighty shallow stack :/.  Doesn't appear anything is wrong.  Therefore, assume nothing! Such as "there isn't an inner exception" (that's why you should always ToString an exception and post the whole thing), or that your filename is correct.  Would have though that an incorrect filename would throw on GetFileAsync, but again, assumptions are the problem here.  Perhaps you should examine the state of `file` prior to calling delete, see if anything indicates an issue.  Verify the path is correct, or use a different overload.  And ToString().  Other than that, JustDecompile DeleteAsync.

Comment: I'm not assuming anything.  The file variable correctly holds the details of the file I told it to open, there literally is no inner exception because I can see it in the exception it's breaking on while debugging, and there are only two overloads, both of which throw that exception.

Comment: According to the answer, you're assuming the filename is correct.  He might be right, and the exception is just misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect there's something wrong with your `path` value. I've already written a [blogpost](http://www.damirscorner.com/InconsistentExceptionsForWinRTFileOperations.aspx) on this subject because WinRT exceptions can be pretty inconsistent and misleading.

I'd suggest two things to help you get to the bottom of things:

1. Check the value of `StorageFile.Path` property and make sure there are no double `\` in it and that it indeed points into `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` folder.
2. Try calling [`FileIO.ReadBufferAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.readbufferasync.aspx) with the same path. You might get a better exception.

Also, why not simply call [`StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync.aspx) if you already have the full path instead of manipulation the string?

Comment: I'll give this a shot on monday, though I figured that since the StorageFile read the file (it knew its mime-type and such) it could find the file just fine.  I guess that's the real assumption that's bad (though I think that makes the WinRT a bad API if thats the case).  Also I didn't know about StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync, most resources I found were loading the folder first.  I'll try using that too.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're leaving a slash prepended to the path you are trying to delete - you're replacing the folder path, which iirc does not include the trailing slash.

Comment: You were correct about the path prepended, but removing the prepended slash didn't help.  Also, the delete method doesn't do anything with the path I'm providing, it's deleting the file it's loading.