# c# winrt delete file

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-runtime

When I delete file like this behind, it throws an exception:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

when `deleteasync`.

```
public static async Task DeleteFile(string fileName, string folderPath)
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFolder sf = await CheckFolder(folderPath);
            StorageFile sfile = await sf.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            if (sfile != null)
            {
                await sfile.DeleteAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Acctually, CheckFolder is a method to create a folder. And, the ns of StorageFodler is Windows.Storage.

Comment: Can you provide code for `CheckFolder(....)` ? Why are you not checking if `sf` is null or not ?

Comment: It is not null. The exception is throwed at "await sfile.DeleteAsync();".

Comment: `Value does not fall within the expected range.` is related to `ArgumentException`. That means there's problem with `sfile`. Post exception stacktrace if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730536/why-am-i-getting-an-argument-exception-when-attempting-to-delete-a-file